# Visual Studio Code - Auto Imports / Quick Fix does not work

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

My VS Code does not auto-import stuff from `node_modules`.

I've tried to make it work on two PCs and one Mac - the result is the same: No suggestions to import as I type, no options when I focus on a symbol and pressing `Ctrl+.`/`Cmd+.` - no quick fix suggestions.

I tried to install [Auto Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) extension - no suggestions.

I read this [release notes post](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#add-all-missing-imports-source-action) about "Add all missing imports" and tried to apply the shortcut - no luck, it does not do anything.

At this point I am completely lost, I see many posts where people ask the same and people suggest them to use Quick Fix by pressing Ctrl+. but as you can see on the screenshot - it does not have any suggestions.

I am using TypeScript but I also tried this with JS - no luck.

On the screenshot I am running my app in WSL but I also tried native run on both Windows and macOS.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[image: Quick Fix Does not suggest to import]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that until recently (before TypeScript 4 release) the only way to make auto-imports work was to import each library you need at least once in your project (does not matter where). After that VS Code supposed to start auto-import stuff from them.

Starting TS 4 the VS Code suppose to start doing it automatically (more concrete - auto-include from all the libraries specified in your `package.json`), though I've noticed that it uses the wrong paths to the code while importing - to the /dist/ folders as opposed to whatever a library exposes. As a result, `Node.js` might not be able to resolve and execute them. [I've created an issue here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40223)

Note that in order this to work at all

- Make sure your VS Code uses TS 4.0.2 or greater (as shown in the bottom right corner, click it to change)
- You may need to set setting `typescript.preferences.includePackageJsonAutoImports` to `on`, because it your imports list exceeds 10 dependencies - it may/won't not scan them. See [release notes for the details](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#smarter-auto-imports).

The bottom line - in order it to work correctly at the moment you still need to import (by hand) a new dependency in your code (anywhere) at least once and then VS Code auto-import will start working for that lib.

Comment: Setting, `typescript.preferences.includePackageJsonAutoImports` to `on` seemed to do the trick for me but only for tsx files. JSX files don't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah, setting `typescript.preferences.includePackageJsonAutoImports` also fixed it for me. The default is 'auto', which has the comment: ` auto: Search dependencies based on estimated performance impact.`. So possibly when things get a bit slow it gets disabled, therefor restarting your computer will likely help!

Answer (score 3):

For me, adding  `"typescript.preferences.includePackageJsonAutoImports": "on"`
to settings.json (or in preferences > settings > Typescript > preferences: Include Package JSON Auto Imports - `on` instead of `auto`) worked

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to enable the built-in VS Code extension "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features".
Go to Extensions, in the search filed, type "@builtin" and Scroll until you find it.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might still not have found what is going on, if you added `// @ts-nocheck` on top of your file, this might also disable the import "Quick fix" while the auto-complete feature will keep working...