# Built-in snippet not working in VS Code for React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, built-in

I am coding a React page with VS Code.

Suddenly, some snippets like `rfce` started not working even if it's never given me problems. I don't know what's wrong.

**picture of before**

[image]

**picture of now**

[image]

What I did recently was just updated `react-router-dom` to version 5.2.0 and `npm install` it.

Comment: Please upload pictures of the errors prompted in vscode if you have any. 
Please also upload pictures of what the expected outcome and the current outcome (what you mean with "not working") is. Some snippets may change their behaviour across versions.

Comment: Install  ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets from Extensions and make sure it is Enabled.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

React snippets are not built-in. That one for example comes from this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets).

Make sure you have it installed and enabled, and that you are working in a file with the proper file extension for them to work.

Answer (score 10):

If on windows, use -rfce instead of _rfce. This worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

Those React snippets what you are talking about are not built-in, those snippets are coming from an extension.
That extension stopped working for you because you may change some of your settings.

1. Make sure you have installed the extension and enabled. Also that: you are working in a file which has the proper file extension (try: .jsx & .tsx).
2. If they are still not working (which was the case at me also), check your settings, because some of the settings can interfere, and make the extension stop working.
3. Open settings.json by: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> , type: settings.json, select: "**Open settings (JSON)**"
4. Check in the settings.json file if the following settings are different than mine:

```
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",     /*make sure this is NOT "none"*/
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "other": true,
      "comments": false,
      "strings": true
    },
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
    "html.suggest.html5": false,
    "typescript.suggest.paths": false,
    "javascript.suggest.paths": false,
```

As a fast experiment you can copy the whole code, paste it at the end of the settings.json, save it, restart VSC, and try it out if now the snippets are working. 
 If it solved your issue, you can sort the commands one-by-one out, to find out which caused the issue of yours.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the same thing. You can try uninstalling and then installing the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) again

Answer (score 1):

1. It might not work, if you use the same file name like Rfce.js
2. Ensure that the file has extension js, ts etc.,
3. Uninstalling and installing React snippet from VSCode Extension might work.
4. Go to Preference - Settings - Extensions - Search for React Snippet and check if the values are correctly checked in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that React snippet is not working properly, try to download it manually and install it through the [link to the vss file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) and now install from Vss option in the extension section

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32137338)

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall the snippet extension I had which was:

React-Native/React/Redux snippets for es6/es7 v2.0.6 by: EQuimper

and I used the extension:
ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets v1.9.3 by:
rodrigovallades

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Launch Quick Open:

- Linux: Ctrl+P
- macOS: ⌘P
- Windows: Ctrl+P

Paste the following command and press Enter:

```
ext install dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you unfortunately uninstall it.

you have to install.

```
ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets
```

in visual studio. Hope it works

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My snippets worked as I thought they should once I fixed auto imports from this post by setting includePackageJsonAutoImports to always on. I used to have to type "-" before they would come up.

[Visual Studio Code - Auto Imports / Quick Fix does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477929/visual-studio-code-auto-imports-quick-fix-does-not-work)